# Two-way binding with Windows Forms ComboBox throws NullReferenceException when changed

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, binding, combobox

I have a Windows Forms application, and one of the forms has a couple of `ComboBox`es that are both bound to the same `BindingList` of objects I have mapped via Entity Framework.

The `Form_Load` event calls this:

```
private void SetFacilityDropdowns()
{
    dbContext.Facilities.Load();
    var bindingSource = dbContext.Facilities.Local.ToBindingList();
    Dictionary<ComboBox, string> selectedDropDownsAndBoundFields = new Dictionary<ComboBox, string>
        {
            {FacilityId,    DataConstants.Facility.FacilityId},
            {FacilityName,  DataConstants.Facility.FacilityName}
        };
    SetDropdowns(bindingSource, selectedDropDownsAndBoundFields);            
}
```

The `SetDropdowns` method looks like this:

```
private static void SetDropdowns<T>(BindingList<T> dataSource, Dictionary<ComboBox, string> dropdownsAndBoundFields)
{
    if (dropdownsAndBoundFields == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    foreach (var dropdown in dropdownsAndBoundFields)
    {
        dropdown.Key.DataSource = dataSource;
        dropdown.Key.DisplayMember = dropdown.Value;
        dropdown.Key.ValueMember = dropdown.Value;
        dropdown.Key.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
        dropdown.Key.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        dropdown.Key.SelectedIndexChanged += Dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }
}
```

Everything looks fine, and both `ComboBox`es appear to contain all of the items that I would expect them to.  However, there are a few `Facility` objects from the `Facilities` table where the `FacilityName` property is `null`.  This appears in the `ComboBox` as an empty string, although I don't know if it is only displayed that way or if it gets converted when it is bound.

Normally, when I change the `FacilityName` dropdown, the `FacilityId` dropdown changes to its matching value.  However, when I change `FacilityName` to one of the null/empty string values, I get a `NullReferenceException` thrown.  It appears to be thrown by the Windows Forms UI thread, so I can't set a breakpoint in any of the `ComboBox` "changed" events, because the exception gets thrown before any of the events get fired.

Any idea why this is happening?

EDIT:

Here is a stack trace:

```
>   NITS.exe!NITS.Program.CurrentDomain_UIThreadException(object sender, System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventArgs t) Line 50   C#
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.OnThreadException(System.Exception t) + 0x8e bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProcException(System.Exception e) + 0x16 bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnThreadException(System.Exception e) + 0xa bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x9b bytes   
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.SendMessage(int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x21 bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ReflectMessageInternal(System.IntPtr hWnd, ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x3b bytes   
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCommand(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x1b bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x3b7 bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x2a bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x5e bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x11 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x35 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x80 bytes   
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x56 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.DefWndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0xa bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseDown(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m, System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons button, int clicks) + 0x3a bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x8da bytes 
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x864 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x11 bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x35 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x80 bytes   
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(System.IntPtr dwComponentID, int reason, int pvLoopData) + 0x24d bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x155 bytes  
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(int reason, System.Windows.Forms.ApplicationContext context) + 0x4a bytes    
    System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(System.Windows.Forms.Form mainForm) + 0x31 bytes  
    NITS.exe!NITS.Program.Main() Line 37 + 0x1d bytes   C#
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) + 0x6b bytes    
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly() + 0x27 bytes  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state) + 0x6f bytes   
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0xa7 bytes  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) + 0x16 bytes  
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) + 0x41 bytes    
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart() + 0x44 bytes   
    [Native to Managed Transition]
```

The exception being thrown looks like this:

```
System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object. System.String get_Text()    at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.get_Text()
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WmReflectCommand(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: Can you show a stacktrace?

Comment: Just added call stack and exception message.

Comment: Then bind a List<> or ObservableCollection<> which do not have empty item(i.e. Null values) to the combobox.

Comment: @RaviPatel then I lose the ability to have the 2 comboboxes linked together so that when I change one, the other is changed accordingly.

Comment: @Douglas Barbin, but you can bind both comboboxes to the same collection. So, if collection changes both comboboxes will change accordingly.

Comment: @RaviPatel If I exclude items from the collection because they are `null` in one of the comboboxes, then I lose that item entirely in both comboboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main exception is obviously

`System.NullReferenceException Object reference not set to an instance of an object. System.String get_Text()    at System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox.get_Text()`

which leads me to believe that your combobox is trying to set the `DisplayMember` property to a null value. Since you said yourself you're not sure if the empty columns coming back from your database are represented as empty strings or null in the `Facility` class, you can explicity convert them in your getters. In addition, if you are passing in a Nullable to your FacilityID property, you need to convert it to an int so the combobox can handle it.

So, in your `Facility` class.

```
    public class Facility
    {
        private string _facilityName;
        private int _facilityID;

        public string FacilityName
        {
            get
            {
                if (_facilityName == null)
                    return String.Empty;
                else
                    return _facilityName;
            }
            set { _facilityName = value; }
        }

        public int FacilityID
        {
            get { return _facilityID; }
            set { _facilityID = value == null ? default(int) : value};
        }
    }
```

Using this, you'll make sure that you never have your control attempting to bind to a null value, and it should rid you of the exception.

Comment: `Facility` is a class that is auto-generated by Entity Framework.

Comment: Can you change the behavior of this class to make sure no null values are returned?

Comment: I can, and this actually works.  I am going to try a few things and then return with my results.

Comment: Okay, that solves the exception problem, but introduces a new one.  When I select one of the null values, the accompanying value in the other dropdown becomes `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Facility_F4B14BF33FD7C299E70286AAFB2DE3802F40B0A50A6BF0EFD80BD6C4385597B6` (or some other long hex string at the end) instead of the correct `FacilityId` value.

Comment: I am going to mark this as the answer, since it removes the exception.

Comment: Okay I've updated the answer. I believe that the error you're getting is from trying to convert a Nullable<int> value into an int. C# can't cast that by default, so you should return `default(int)` in that case. Hope it helps. Good luck.

Comment: Last comment isn't useful at all. `FacilityId` is the table's primary key and can never be nullable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try maybe to use IntelliTrace to get more info?